# Is there a standard class for an infinitely nested defaultdict?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, infinite, defaultdict

Does anyone know if there's a standard class for an infinitely nestable dictionary in Python?

I'm finding myself repeating this pattern:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)))
d['abc']['def']['xyz'] += 1
```

If I want to add "another layer" (e.g. `d['abc']['def']['xyz']['wrt']`), I have to define another nesting of defaultdicts.

To generalize this pattern, I've written a simple class that overrides `__getitem__` to automatically create the next nested dictionary.

e.g.

```
d = InfiniteDict(('count',0),('total',0))
d['abc']['def']['xyz'].count += 0.24
d['abc']['def']['xyz'].total += 1
d['abc']['def']['xyz']['wrt'].count += 0.143
d['abc']['def']['xyz']['wrt'].total += 1
```

However, does anyone know of a pre-existing implementation of this idea? I've tried Googling, but I'm not sure what this would be called.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can derive from `defaultdict` to get the behavior you want:

```
class InfiniteDict(defaultdict):
   def __init__(self):
      defaultdict.__init__(self, self.__class__)

class Counters(InfiniteDict):
   def __init__(self):
      InfiniteDict.__init__(self)                                               
      self.count = 0
      self.total = 0

   def show(self):
      print "%i out of %i" % (self.count, self.total)
```

Usage of this class would look like this:

```
>>> d = Counters()
>>> d[1][2][3].total = 5
>>> d[1][2][3].show()
0 out of 5
>>> d[5].show()
0 out of 0
```

Comment: Thanks. This comes the closest to what I was looking for, and helped me find the *exact* solution.

Answer (score 29):

I think this one-liner is a nearly perfect solution:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> infinite_defaultdict = lambda: defaultdict(infinite_defaultdict)
>>> d = infinite_defaultdict() 
>>> d['x']['y']['z'] = 10
```

by Raymond Hettinger on Twitter (https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/343823801278140417)

Comment: this solution should be ranked higher!

Comment: elegant as  Prada

Answer (score 15):

This lends itself naturally to a recursive definition.

```
>>> import collections
>>> def nested_dd():
...     return collections.defaultdict(nested_dd)
...
>>> foo = nested_dd()
>>> foo
defaultdict(<function nested_dd at 0x023F0E30>, {})
>>> foo[1][2]=3
>>> foo[1]
defaultdict(<function nested_dd at 0x023F0E30>, {2: 3})
>>> foo[1][2]
3
```

Comment: Very tidy, but has the same flaw as my posted answer, no support for 'count' and 'total' zero values at the leaf nodes.

Comment: @Paul -- indeed; you can't have your cake and eat it too! Having special support for `count` and `total` breaks symmetry, so it would have to be hardwired into the class somewhere.

Comment: @aaronasterling: There is not problem with any recursion limits since the function doesn't call itself recursively.

Comment: right, I missed that part and kept looking :) Sorry katriealex.

Comment: pardon me, but i don't think this working because if you see the question of the OP he is doing a lot calculation using the default value of the defaultdict and not just assignment !!!

Answer (score 4):

The ideal solution, inspired by sth's answer:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class InfiniteDict(defaultdict):
   def __init__(self, **kargs):
      defaultdict.__init__(self, lambda: self.__class__(**kargs))
      self.__dict__.update(kargs)

d = InfiniteDict(count=0, total=0)
d['abc']['def'].count += 0.25
d['abc']['def'].total += 1
print d['abc']['def'].count
print d['abc']['def'].total
d['abc']['def']['xyz'].count += 0.789
d['abc']['def']['xyz'].total += 1
print d['abc']['def']['xyz'].count
print d['abc']['def']['xyz'].total
```

Answer (score 4):

In case after eight years you are still thinking about how to get this with a one-liner:

```
from collections import defaultdict

t = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(t.default_factory))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is close:

```
class recursivedefaultdict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, attrFactory=int):
        self.default_factory = lambda : type(self)(attrFactory)
        self._attrFactory = attrFactory
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        newval = self._attrFactory()
        setattr(self, attr, newval)
        return newval

d = recursivedefaultdict(float)
d['abc']['def']['xyz'].count += 0.24  
d['abc']['def']['xyz'].total += 1  

data = [
    ('A','B','Z',1),
    ('A','C','Y',2),
    ('A','C','X',3),
    ('B','A','W',4),
    ('B','B','V',5),
    ('B','B','U',6),
    ('B','D','T',7),
    ]

table = recursivedefaultdict(int)
for k1,k2,k3,v in data:
    table[k1][k2][k3] = v
```

<strike>It's not quite what you want, since the most deeply nested level does not have your default 0 values for 'count' or 'total'.</strike>

Edited:
Ah, this works now - just needed to add a `__getattr__` method, and this does what you want.

Edit 2:
Now you can define other factory methods for the attributes, besides ints.  But they all have to be the same type, can't have count be float and total be int.

Comment: Minor suggestion: you could use `functools.partial(type(self), attrFactory)`.