# How can I get Python to automatically create missing key/value pairs in a dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm creating a dictionary structure that is several levels deep.  I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
dict = {}
dict['a']['b'] = True
```

At the moment the above fails because key 'a' does not exist.  At the moment I have to check at every level of nesting and manually insert an empty dictionary.  Is there some type of syntactic sugar to be able to do something like the above can produce:

```
{'a': {'b': True}}
```

Without having to create an empty dictionary at each level of nesting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178249/infinitely-nested-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As others have said, use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). This is the idiom I prefer for arbitrarily-deep nesting of dictionaries:

```
def nested_dict():
    return collections.defaultdict(nested_dict)

d = nested_dict()
d[1][2][3] = 'Hello, dictionary!'
print(d[1][2][3]) # Prints Hello, dictionary!
```

This also makes checking whether an element exists a little nicer, too, since you may no longer need to use `get`:

```
if not d[2][3][4][5]:
    print('That element is empty!')
```

---

This has been edited to use a `def` rather than a lambda for [pep8 compliance](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations). The original lambda form looked like this below, which has the drawback of being called `<lambda>` everywhere instead of getting a proper function name.

```
>>> nested_dict = lambda: collections.defaultdict(nested_dict)
>>> d = nested_dict()
>>> d[1][2][3]
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x037E7540>, {})
```

Comment: That's an elegant implementation.

Comment: Oh, wow, I've never considered a recursive factory before. I'd use `def` to define the `nested_dict` function though, rather than a lambda.

Comment: Great answer. Just one hint on this: `pickle` can not handle it by default: `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'd.<locals>.<lambda>'`

Comment: @gies0r you mean this problem happens when "saving the dict as pickle" or "loading the pickle into dict"?

Comment: @LukAron saving the dict as pickle

Comment: [Named lambdas are bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38381663/4518341). Use a `def` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

[Python: defaultdict of defaultdict?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5029934/139010)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this, since `dict()` function can handle `**kwargs`:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict

```
print dict(a=dict(b=True))
# {'a': {'b' : True}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the depth of your data structure is fixed (that is, you know in advance that you need `mydict[a][b][c]` but not `mydict[a][b][c][d]`), you can build a nested defaultdict structure using `lambda` expressions to create the inner structures:

```
two_level = defaultdict(dict)
three_level = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
four_level = defaultdict(lamda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict)))
```