# Python: Append Dictionary new element

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, multidimensional-array

Convert PHP code:

`$this->plane[$slice_id][$f][] = array('x' => $y, 'y' => $z);`

To python:

`self.plane = {};`

`self.plane[slice_id][f][] = {'x' : y, 'y' : z};`

Does not work.

1) `self.plane[slice_id][f]` -> not yet initialized. Only create this element if necessary.

2) `[]` -> push element to array

3) Python dictionary are not usually multi-dimensional

Comment: In Python the closest to PHP's array is an [infinite defaultdict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178249/infinitely-nested-dictionary-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
self.plane[slice_id][f] = [] 
self.plane[slice_id][f].append( {'x' : y, 'y' : z} )
```

The method `append()` appends a passed `obj` into the existing list.

`self.plane[slice_id][f][] = {'x' : y, 'y' : z};` is not valid syntax for the python

**Demo**

```
>>> new_list = []
>>> new_list[] = 'test'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    new_list[] = 'test'
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```