# Reading from nested json and getting None type Error -> try/except

Tags: python, json

I am reading data from nested json with this code:

```
data = json.loads(json_file.json)
for nodesUni in data["data"]["queryUnits"]['nodes']:
        try:
            tm = (nodesUni['sql']['busData'][0]['engine']['engType'])
        except:
            tm = ''
        try:
            to = (nodesUni['sql']['carData'][0]['engineData']['producer']['engName'])
        except:
            to = ''
        json_output_for_one_GU_owner = {
            "EngineType": tm,
            "EngineName": to,
        }
```

I am having an issue with None type error (eg. this one doesn't exists at all `nodesUni['sql']['busData'][0]['engine']['engType']` cause there are no data, so I am using try/except. But my code is more complex and having a try/except for every value is crazy. Is there any other option how to deal with this?

Error: "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: Why are you iterating over `nodesUni["owners"]["edges"]` if you never use `edgesGU` variable?

Comment: corrected,  I've tried to make the code easier.

Comment: Update your question with the exact error

Comment: bare except is bad practice. You should use `KeyError` and `IndexError` (for indices). This is not trivial if you want to create any level without errors.

Comment: If you know where the missing data is likely to be, you may be able to use `.get()` to provide a default value.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know when the data is missing. Can be everywhere. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is non-trivial as your requirement is to traverse the dictionaries without errors, and get an empty string value in the end, all that in a very simple expression like cascading the `[]` operators.

### First method

My approach is to add a hook when loading the json file, so it creates default dictionaries in an infinite way

```
import collections,json

def superdefaultdict():
    return collections.defaultdict(superdefaultdict)

def hook(s):
    c = superdefaultdict()
    c.update(s)
    return(c)

data = json.loads('{"foo":"bar"}',object_hook=hook)

print(data["x"][0]["zzz"])   # doesn't exist
print(data["foo"])  # exists
```

prints:

```
defaultdict(<function superdefaultdict at 0x000001ECEFA47160>, {})
bar
```

when accessing some combination of keys that don't exist (at any level), `superdefaultdict` recursively creates a `defaultdict` of itself (this is a nice pattern, you can read more about it in [Is there a standard class for an infinitely nested defaultdict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178249/is-there-a-standard-class-for-an-infinitely-nested-defaultdict)), allowing any number of non-existing key levels.

Now the only drawback is that it returns a `defaultdict(<function superdefaultdict at 0x000001ECEFA47160>, {})` which is ugly. So

```
print(data["x"][0]["zzz"] or "")
```

prints empty string if the dictionary is empty. That should suffice for your purpose.

Use like that in your context:

```
def superdefaultdict():
    return collections.defaultdict(superdefaultdict)

def hook(s):
    c = superdefaultdict()
    c.update(s)
    return(c)

data = json.loads(json_file.json,object_hook=hook)
for nodesUni in data["data"]["queryUnits"]['nodes']:
    tm = nodesUni['sql']['busData'][0]['engine']['engType'] or ""
    to = nodesUni['sql']['carData'][0]['engineData']['producer']['engName'] or ""
```

Drawbacks:

- It creates a lot of empty dictionaries in your `data` object. Shouldn't be a problem (except if you're *very* low in memory) as the object isn't dumped to a file afterwards (where the non-existent values would appear)
- If a value already exists, trying to access it as a dictionary crashes the program
- Also if some value is `0` or an empty list, the `or` operator will pick `""`. This can be workarounded with another wrapper that tests if the object is an empty `superdefaultdict` instead. Less elegant but doable.

### Second method

Convert the access of your successive dictionaries as a string (for instance just double quote your expression like `"['sql']['busData'][0]['engine']['engType']"`, parse it, and loop on the keys to get the data. If there's an exception, stop and return an empty string.

```
import json,re,operator

def get(key,data):
    key_parts = [x.strip("'") if x.startswith("'") else int(x) for x in re.findall(r"\[([^\]]*)\]",key)]
    try:
        for k in key_parts:
            data = data[k]
        return data
    except (KeyError,IndexError,TypeError):
        return ""
```

testing with some simple data:

```
data = json.loads('{"foo":"bar","hello":{"a":12}}')

print(get("['sql']['busData'][0]['engine']['engType']",data))
print(get("['hello']['a']",data))
print(get("['hello']['a']['e']",data))
```

we get, empty string (some keys are missing), 12 (the path is valid), empty string (we tried to traverse a non-dict existing value).

The syntax could be simplified (ex: `"sql"."busData".O."engine"."engType"`) but would still have to retain a way to differentiate keys (strings) from indices (integers)

The second approach is probably the most flexible one.

Comment: I am not sure I understand well how it works. I have somewhere [defaultdict(<function superdefaultdict at 0x7fee5a9a7940>] but somewhere (same level same node, same value) is still None type and failing on TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: For instance, it happens when you have a `null` value in your json file and you try to traverse it.

Comment: so also when the field doesnot exists at all? 
eg. for     `(nodesUni['sql']['busData'][0]['engine']['engType']` -> where engine is None in json and engType does not exists at all.

Comment: try my second approach. It does what you want.