# Python InfiniteDefaultRevisionDictionary, any implementations?

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict, revision, infinite-recursion

In programming, certain dictionary-based data structures are very useful and important. For example:

1. Revision dictionary:
   Revision dictionary is a sub-type of dictionary that keeps keys sorted in the order of last modification. It is commonly used in cache handling which remembers most recently used items.
2. Default dictionary:
   Default dictionary can return a default element when the dictionary is accessed with a key that is not present in the dictionary. It already has an implementation in `collections.defaultdict`.
3. Infinite dictionary:
   An infinite dictionary can be accessed with infinitely layer of nested recursion, i.e., infinite chaining of keys, e.g., `dct[person_name][gender], dct[company_name][employees]`, it can be used to create dynamic data structures, or even modeling file-system structures.

So my question is that: in Python, is it possible to write a dictionary that has all the 3 features, i.e., an infinite default revision dictionary? In particular, one can specify options during creation, e.g., whether the items should be sorted in the order of insertion, or keys' order, or revision order. And how to implement if possible?

It would be very cool if future-version Python has a built-in Dictionary class that supports all of these features and options.

**Edits**:
Point 2 might not be in contradiction with Point 3, that in principle, an InfiniteDefaultRevisionDictionary can have a default key other than lambda of itself. For example, if the default key is 0, then:

```
dd=InfiniteDefaultRevisionDictionary(default=0, {})
print(dd['a']['b']['c']) # should give 0
dd['b']['c'][2] = [1, '2', 3.5] # should work fine
```

Comment: For the "revision dictionary", look at the `LastUpdatedOrderedDict` recipe in the docs for `collections.OrderedDict`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects. Generally, subclassing `OrderedDict` would be a good starting point for what you want to achieve here.

Comment: For #3 this might be of interest: [infinitely nested default dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178249) and specifically the Raymond Hettinger approach.

Comment: If 3. is fulfilled, the default item is always a special `defaultdict` which may contradict to 2.

Comment: @MichaelButscher , I wonder whether can an infinite dictionary be not of defaultdict? Actually, I only need 3 special capabilities: revision/last-update ordered, infinite, and default. So no contradiction.

Comment: Thanks @slothrop , that is the shortest code I can find.

Comment: @slothrop, how to keep the items in keys' sorted order? I need an option that can select sorting order.

Comment: I assumed that the default dictionary in 2. should be able to provide other default values like e. g. an integer 0 or so. In such a case, it would contradict to 3.

Comment: @xuancong84 I'd suggest overriding `__setitem__`. If you look at the source code, the `OrderedDict` maintains a linked list of keys. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L113 So it should be pretty straightforward to override this such that a new key is inserted in a position that maintains sorted order.

Comment: @MichaelButscher , I realize that an InfiniteDefaultRevisionDictionary can have a default value other than itself: e.g., let's say `default_value=0`, then `print(dct['a']['b']['c'])` will give 0, but it still allow chaining of keys even if initially `'a'` is not in `dct`, and `'b'` is not in `dct['a']`, and so on. So 2 might not necessarily contradicts with 3. However, this might not fit into the logic of Python programming language.

Comment: That is what I meant. The restrictions of the Python language don't allow arbitrary defaults and arbitrary nesting at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who have replied!
Combining suggestions from various people as well as my own research, below is the most I can do.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
InfiniteDefaultRevisionDict sort items in the order of latest updates and allows arbitrary chaining of keys.

For example,

>>> d=InfiniteDefaultRevisionDict()
>>> dct[person_name][gender] = 'M'
>>> dct[company_name][employees] = [...]
"""

import bisect, json
from collections import namedtuple
from collections.abc import MutableMapping


from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict

class Dict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, default=None, init_dct={}):
        self._default = default
        self.update(init_dct)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        self.move_to_end(key)

    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = self._default() if callable(self._default) else self._default
        return self[key]

    def to_json(self, fp=None, **kwargs):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda t: dict(t), **kwargs) if fp==None else json.dump(self, fp, default=lambda t: dict(t), **kwargs)

    def from_json(self, fp=None, data=''):
        self.update(json.loads(data, object_hook=lambda t: (Dict(self._default, t) if type(t)==dict else t)) if fp==None \
            else json.load(fp, object_hook=lambda t: (Dict(self._default, t) if type(t)==dict else t)))
        return self


InfiniteDefaultRevisionDict = lambda: Dict(InfiniteDefaultRevisionDict)
```

It cannot set the default lambda other than `InfiniteDefaultRevisionDict`. However, you can serialize it to JSON and de-serialize it from JSON in the form of a standard Python `dict`. Hope someone can come up with a better solution that can satisfy more requirements.